# PowerShell Graph API: Invalid audience

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am facing a problem since this morning. I am using the Graph API for Powershell to create M365 Groups. Until yesterday this worked fine. Today I am getting this error if I try to create a new group:

```
New-MgGroup : Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({ body = Micros...ftGraphGroup1 }:<>f__AnonymousType1`1) [New-MgGroup
   _CreateExpanded], RestException`1
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidAuthenticationToken,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.NewMgGroup_CreateExpanded
```

Nothing changed in my script. I am generating a Token this way:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com -Interactive
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken (Get-PnPGraphAccessToken)
New-MgGroup
```

I checked the token on https://jwt.ms/ and it looks normal. Audience is https://tenant.sharepoint.com

Comment: I am able to see the exact error and I think it is expected because the access token is for sharpoint. Was this working before for creating Groups? What scopes were added in your token before?

Answer (score 0):

Your token contains an invalid audience for MS Graph. Try using **Connect-MgGraph** without the access token issued from **Connect-PnPOnline**.

The **aud** claim contains the intended audience for the token. In your case it is not graph which should be **00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000**

If you can provide the full error you get including the request id and timestamp, we can be able to check what happened.

```
Connect-MgGraph
New-MgGroup -description "Desc" -displayName "Name" -mailEnabled:$false  -mailNickname "mailnc" -securityEnabled
```